# Laravel Session access through Middleware Methods - Session store not set on request

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5

I am setting a session during `auth/register` (Laravel Signup Auth) functionality.
When I try to access the `session` `my_user_referral_session`  I set during `auth/register` in the method which is executed immediately after Signup.

I am getting following error

```
RuntimeException in Request.php line 870:
Session store not set on request.
```

My Routes.php file

```
Route::get("/dashboard","DashboardController@dashboard");
```

DashboardController.php

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('auth');
} 

public function dashboard() {
    $request = new \Illuminate\Http\Request();

    if($request->session()->has("my_user_referral_session")){
     /* Reading session data set during Laravel auth/register 
    }
```

[image]

Note: When I use `session()` helper method it works without any error, but I need to remove the session , which is not in `session()` helper methods.

Notice: $this->middleware('auth'); in the construct. I suspect this is causing issue

Comment: Currently i am using `session("my_user_referral_session",NULL)` to reset the session value. Which is working. I dont know how to remove `session` through `laravel 5.2` helper methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the session with `session()->forget('my_user_referral_session');`

Session is not bound to the request.

Comment: When i use `$request->session()->get('my_user_referral_session')` it throws the above error. But there is no error when i use `session("my_user_referral_session")`.

Comment: @abdulrashid Which Laravel version are you using? Does the route have `web` middleware applied? And you can just do `session()->forget()` instead of `$request->session()->forget()`.

Comment: class 'Illuminate\Session\Store' does not have a method 'forgot'

Comment: @abdulrashid It is `forget` not `forgot`.

Comment: `session()->forget("my_key")` works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: so Why $request->session()->get("user_referral_tracking_id")  didn't worked?   When I try applying `Web` `Middleware` I get 500 Error
`Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::get("/dashboard","DashboardController@dashboard");
});`

Comment: @abdulrashid Because session is not bound to the request as stated in my answer. Also that error is probably because it already has the web middleware applied. You can check with `php artisan route:list`.

Comment: `Laravel 5.2`. I can see `web,auth` in the route list for `DashboardController@dashboard`. All method under dashboard needs user authentication. Cookie based Session authentication. Am I missing something here in `middlewaregroups`

Answer (score 0):

I think the line

```
$request = new \Illuminate\Http\Request();
```

creates a new "empty" request, so there is no session data there.

The best way to get the session data there is to use the session() helper:

```
session('my_user_referral_session')
```

will return your required information or null if there is no session data with that key.